# Docker searching for repository when building base image locally

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile and base image on my machine. I am attempting to build the image using the Dockerfile commands but after Docker loads the base image, it errors out and says it can't reach a machine. Unsure where this definition is.

I issued command,

```
docker build -t container-name -f Dockerfile .
```

It sucks in the base image "Sending build context to Docker daemon" up to the full file size of the base image. But then it says:
"Step 1/10 : FROM base-image
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on : read udp  -> : i/o timeout

Unsure why it's trying to access a registry when I have the definition and base file in that same directory.

Comment: The name of the base image is `base-image` ?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `docker images` in the description above.

Comment: I just used filler names. It's on a separate work network, so I have to do everything locally only. Docker images has two images left of 3  containers we run. I removed the image I intended to update with new software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I had not loaded the base image using the Docker Load command...

It was not listed in my "docker images" Repository, therefore it was looking elsewhere.

So, if using your own local image, use:

```
docker load -i <base_image.tar.gz>
```

Then it will be in your "docker images" list, and now you can perform the command:
docker build -t  -f Dockerfile .

where the Dockerfile contains first line:

```
FROM base_image
```

...